# delete spaces and characters in a txt list

Tags: python

i have an issue with a python script, i have a .txt list with a permutation like this:

```
[(1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)]
[(1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0)]
[(1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1)]
...
```

my code to delete spaces and characters is the next:

```
import re

inn = ''
with open('permutations.txt', 'r') as file:
     inn = file.read()

with open('permutations2.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(re.sub(r'[[(n\\n)]]','', inn))
```

I need the resulting list to be like this:

```
1,0,2,2,1,2,1,2,2
1,0,2,2,1,2,2,0,0
1,0,2,2,1,2,2,0,1
```

but only deletes the last characters ,how can i solve it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation like this it is probably easier to find the thing you want rather than replace the stuff you don't. It seems like you just want all the numbers separated by a comma. This might be clearer:

```
 # find all numbers and join them with commas
 fixed = ",".join(re.findall(r'\d+', line))
```

Then you can read through your input while writing to your output line by line:

```
import re

with open(infile, 'r') as inF, open(outfile, 'w') as outF:
    for line in inF:
        fixed = ",".join(re.findall(r'\d+', line))
        outF.write(fixed + "\n")
```

With your input this should write:

```
1,0,2,2,1,2,1,2,2
1,0,2,2,1,2,2,0,0
1,0,2,2,1,2,2,0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing your in file to a string, consider using a list.

You can still strip() elements of your list of whatever you wish, and then write them to your out file, joined by commas

As far as characters, what are you trying to delete?

Comment: im gonna to try write it as you indicated me, and i im trying to quit the parentesis ( ) and this other [ ], thank you

Comment: I see. Consider, also, reading in or storing only the values you wish, instead of grabbing the entire contents and trying to strip().